# OllyDgb1.10 API help file not working

Tags: ollydbg

I pointed the API help file to `WIN32.HLP` (Help -> Select API File -> win32.hlp -> Open)

But when I right click on API and click 'Help on Symbolic name' 'Windows Help and Support' comes up and shows me 'Why can't I get Help from this program? '.

What is the problem here...I'm using win 7, 64 Bit.

Comment: could you post your edit as an answer?

Comment: Sorry i don't hav enough rep points....I jst got started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(on behalf of the OP)

Solved it. It was because my system was missing one update.

Check the error details and solution [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607). Modern Windows versions have no more built-in support for the old Windows help format, so that needs to be installed explicitly.

Comment: Still not working, the following error message appears: `Cannot display this help file. Try opening the help file again, and if you still get this message, copy the help file to a different drive, and try again.`